# crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated in React and Laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel, server

I am using React(17.0.2) as front end and Laravel8 is back end.
And my subdomain like
app.example.com
This working fine. But in some networks I got error like this
[image]

And I created another subdomains called app2.example.com and demo.example.com. These two URLs working fine in all networks.  app.example.com only problem.
I don't know this is React, Laravel or server issue. How to solve this issue?
Thanks

Comment: Not sure what the question is. The message is not relevant to the reason you might be seeing that screen in chrome. The message is more relevant to the screen itself